# How can you fold a rectangular piece of paper once to get an 8 sided polygon?

Tags: geometry

If you start with a rectangular piece of paper, how can you fold it once to get an 8 sided polygon?

I am sure the solution is straightforward, but after trying some possibilities, I was unable to come up with such a construction. Could somebody show the solution of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it. Hope this helps.

[image]